# Tunnel Linux traffic to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, tunneling, tunnel, gre

I have two servers. Windows and Linux. Let's say Linux has the IP 1.2.3.4 and Windows 5.6.7.8. I want all traffic to be forwarded to windows as a tunnel. If I connect with 1.2.3.4:329 I want to connect with 5.6.7.8:329.

Allright
Linux (ubuntu) server - IP 1.2.3.4
Windows server - IP 5.6.7.8

I want to push all traffic through Linux to Windows. By means of a GRE tunnel or the like.

I hope someone has an idea how to do this and whether this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iptables to forward all traffic from Linux to Windows.

Add the following line to /etc/sysctl first:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Then run the following command as root:

```
# sysctl -p
```

Forward traffic with iptables command running by root:

```
# sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 329 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8:329
# sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 5.6.7.8 --dport 329-j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
# sudo iptables -t nat -L -n
```

Wish it working.